# Do we “exit”, “quit” or "close" an application?

Tags: terminology, text

Do we “exit” an application, do we “quit” an application, do we “close” an application?

This is in relation to a desktop app. What is the most meaningful term to use?

Comment: Windows command line ftp client may be instructive here (or not): You "close" the connection, then "quit" the client, then "exit" the command window!

Comment: I like to "terminate" and "shut down" applications. Sounds powerful >:)

Comment: I kill applications.

Comment: @simon - What do you feel when you kill applications?

Comment: @simon killing an application has a very specific meaning for an application developer: it is ending the application with brute force (ie through the task manager) instead of using the application's options to end its execution.

Comment: And when you absolutely, positively need to get the job done: 7-pass zero-fill format :)

Comment: The majority of non-developer computer users seem to prefer "X out".... not that you should adopt their customs :)

Comment: Sometimes, I endlessly minimize an application to the task bar... (just don't be one of those programs, and we can be friends).

Comment: For a normal user, aren't they synonyms when applied to desktop programs?

Comment: @MarjanVenema: It all depends … Sending e.g. `kill -TERM` to an application that handles signals properly would shut it down in a proper way.

Comment: @Sukminder: hmm, maybe. I also know of "proper signal processors" that do the same on receiving a stop or quit. Most of the time a kill command sent to any server type application is used to forcefully shut down a connection to the server that is causing some kind of trouble and not to shut down the server itself. For a "shut down yourself nicely" command "kill" is not very good name.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: _arguably_ kill is not a good name for the `kill` utility, as it's sometimes in fact used for signals that don't even have anything to do with ending a process (e.g., [request the status of a running `dd` process](http://askubuntu.com/a/215521/91549)). Nothing we can do about that... due to its inclusion in unix "kill" has received such a jargon meaning. The only thing that would still sound properly martial to a hacker is "kill-nine".

Comment: I quit my job and exited the shop, just before they closed. Now that we have a visual of how each of those words are used, the answer should become apparent. Personally, I would've asked this question on the English.stackexchange.com website - but meh. It's a good question anyway.

Comment: We close windows or mobile apps, or connectins. We quit VIM. We command-Q Mac apps, and I think we alt-X to exit Windows apps? If you are designing a desktop app, it's usually best to stick with the existing patterns in place for that operating system.

Comment: Exit = generic term; quit = a non-technical term for killing the process (Mac); close = close the window, the process can still be running; kill = kill the process

Answer (score 317, accepted):

If you are developing a Windows application, the correct term to use is "Exit". This is spelt out in Microsoft's [Design apps for the Windows desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742392.aspx) guide, under the "Standard Menu Bars" section.

If you are developing a Mac application, the correct term to use is "Quit". (Your menu item must read "Quit *AppName*".) This is spelt out in Apple's [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Menus/Menus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000356-TP6), under "The App Menu" section.

In general, you should follow the platform's user-interface guidelines when you are developing apps so that your app is consistent with all other apps in the same platform, so as to reduce your app's complexity and learning curve for your customers.

Comment: In the Windows context, `close`ing the last windows normally `exit`s the application, whereas this does not have to be the case on an Apple OS. Stick to the Interface Guidelines of the OS to provide a consistent experience for your user on the given OS is good advice.

Comment: For Windows, it depends on the context. Typically an app will have **`"Exit"`** on the standard (**`"File"`**) menu, and **`"Close"`** on the system menu. Notpad, Thunderbird, Firefox all have the typical **`"File"`->`"Exit"`**, and **`"System-menu"`->`"Close"`**. But there are exceptions. Windows Explorer (at least on Win 7) has **`"File"`->`"Close"`**, and **`"System-menu"`->`"Close"`**. Command prompt (**`"cmd.exe"`**) has **`"System-menu"`->`"Close"`**, and you type **`Exit`** to **`Quit`/`Close`/`Exit`**. As you recommend, it's best to stick with the standards for the OS.

Comment: @Kevin Which makes perfect sense, since exiting is something you do from "within" the app, while closing is something you (tell the system to) do from the "outside".

Comment: Also UI guidelines for other OSs might vary: for example, Gnome GUI for Linux explicitly differenciate Closing a window but Quitting an app: https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/3.10/hig-book.html#the-file-menu

Comment: What a pain in the butt if you are developing a cross-platform application. I can see the branching statements now, `if (isMac()){/*tell user to quit*/}else if(isWin()){/*tell user to exit*/}else{/*you're dealing with an educated user, let them call it what they want*/}`

Comment: @RomanBruckner I disagree there. "Close" on Windows usually means closing the current window or tab only. A good example is Notepad++ on Windows, where there are two separate options on the File menu: "Exit" and "Close." If I click "Exit", all tabs will close, but if I choose "Close" only the active tab will close.

Comment: @nullability however I believe the red X in the upper right of the window chrome is the close button, which will exit the application if clicked.

Comment: @Andy It will exit the application, but only because it's the only window open. If I have multiple windows open, the red X will only close the current window and leave the application running on other windows.

Comment: You will not need branching statements in the code of cross-platform applications, @SnakeDoc, as you probably want to build the UI differently for different platforms. Even for the same platform localised into different languages, you will want to have separate resources, not just to cater to different text, but also to different length of strings that may affect the layout of the UI.

Comment: It would have been good though, if the terminology didn't vary with the platform. A simple way to state it would be that one "Opens" a GUI application and the opposite of it being to "Close" an application. Running an application could refer to an algorithm or a back-end process which is 'run' and then 'terminated' (rather than 'exit' or 'quit').

Comment: @nullability That's true, but its valid to say you're closing the application.  The OS is asking the application to close, I think its fair to say exit is internal to the app and close is external.

Comment: @KevinFegan because you never exit Windows Explorer.

Comment: *INSUFFICIENT UNIX IN THE HOUSE*. For UNIX processes at a command-line level, the standard term is [`kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill). "Killing" is just as ambiguous as "closing" though -- you can `kill` a process with one of a set of signals, only some of which make it terminate. However, the command `kill -9` is [famous](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fow7iUaKrq4) for being *totally unambiguous*: It sends the `SIGKILL` signal, which immediately cuts off resource access at `init` level, giving the target process no chance to react.

Comment: @Anko Kill is a term for a different situation and not really UNIX specific in general. Kill is not the normal means of ending the application, but rather by forceful means. For example in Windows the command line tool is called taskkill (hence 'kill' would be an appropriate term for terminating a process in this instance, but not in the normal way, as this question is discussing). In UNIX especially there is also a difference between SIGKILL and SIGTERM. These are indeed UNIX specific and probably only appropriate for programmers or system administrator audiences anyway.

Answer (score 75):

## The Terms

The following table summarises the conventional terms, which are platform dependent.

[image: A table showing the various terms used]

On Windows, you **run** an application, then **exit** it. Ditto for Unix command line tools. However, both old documentation and pretty much all windows 8 documentation uses **Open/Close**.

On a Mac (which deep inside is Unix-based) you **open** an application, but then **quit** it.

You **close** a window or a tab (both you can also **open**).

Sources: [Mac Basic](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2476), [OS X User Experience Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/UEGuidelines/UEGuidelines.html), [Windows 7 Using Programs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-programs#1TC=windows-7), [Windows 8 Getting Around your PC Guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/getting-around-tutorial).

## The Argument

Consider the following when deciding on a term to use:

- **Run** - A nearly pure programmers' term. Technical novices shall not understand why you 'run' programs.
- **Exit** - Some users may think (based on real world experience) that when you exit something you can return to it.
- **Close** - Same as the previous one, when you close something you can re-open it. There might be some confusion with *closing windows* here as well. Notice that you can have two types of behaviours depending on the OS:

  - The application **truly terminates** (like would be on Windows 98).
  - Or it just **moves to the background** (like on Windows 8 - where you can really open/close/quit). So I would suggest keeping this term *close* to this type of behaviour.
- **Open** - The term is generally not ambiguous.
- **Quit** - Should signify to the user that the application does terminate completely (rather than stay at the background).

Comment: I would also say that you can `Halt` command line tools.

Comment: And many will take `quit` as well.

Comment: Halt sounds more like pausing, indicating you can resume/continue the action later.

Comment: A Halt does not imply pausing, in fact, to shut down the *nix's, you Halt the OS.

Comment: [For completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal), don't forget Interrupt, Stop and Kill - these all apply to using the Mac command line. There are [a lot more signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals) that all have their own meanings and uses aside from ending a program.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: well, even having some idea of where the name **halt(8)** comes from, I still think Halt sounds more like the default action for `^Z` (send SIGSTOP) than anything else.  So, basically, I agree with @JuhaUntinen here.

Comment: Mac OS is Unix based... NOW. After OSX came out. The terminology is left over from the old days. Up to System 7, it was written in PASCAL. o_O

Comment: @SamB, then you disagree with [Alan Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: But let's not forget that the keyboard shortcut for "Exit" on Windows usually is `Ctrl+Q` (for Quit)… :-)

Comment: @jonahb: did Alan Turing so much as *hear* of a user interface?

Comment: @Denis It's simply because `Ctrl+X` is used for cut. You know, it's usually E'x'it, not 'E'xit (especially in File menu). Also, a lot of programs (notepad, calc, wordpad, IE, and so on...) in Windows don't support `Ctrl+Q` for exit. There is `Alt+F4` - a universal shortcut.

Comment: @Naetmul: The use of Ctrl+Q is not because Ctrl+X was taken, since both were stolen at the same time from Mac OS.  Microsoft originally used key combinations with no mnemonic value (F1? F3? Alt+F4? F5? WTF!?) and then stole many of the well-thought-out keystrokes from the Mac, switching Command to Control.

Comment: I am not for the usage of halt in any way, but **halt** is not purely associated with a pause: In Java, we have `Runtime.getRuntime().halt()` which is the most abrupt way one could terminate the program. @MattDiamant

Comment: What is your basis for the Unix command line tool terminology? Normally command line tools run very quickly and have no general need for an "exit" nor a "quit" command, but there are interactive commands like vim, top, more and less. For these tools that I just thought of, for example, the commands to exit those programs appear to be mnemonics for "quit" rather than "exit" as you suggest (vim = :q, top = q, more = q, less = q). Interactive terminals may differ  - In Bash you 'exit' but in Python you 'quit()' and in other interactive command lines it may differ.

Answer (score 20):

**Exit**

I don't know if your user base is international but I guess it is of varying levels of English and varying levels of IT skills. Exit is universal for leave, quit and go away (remember not everyone thinks like us geeks!)

**Take these users:**

### The grandma who has just got her first laptop

**I want this to go away ... quit** [negative connotations, implies it is final, sometimes forever]

**I want this to go away ... exit** [can be related to in [real life]](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4078/4905840447_49389bdf87.jpg)

### The person who speaks enough English to get by

**I want this to go away ... leave** [localised terminology, can also mean "to leave something in a room" - confusing to those not fluent in the context]

**I want this to go away ... exit** [globally recognised terminology, doesn't need context - can stand alone strongly]

I am sure there are more examples I could bore you with but I guess you get the gist. Just think about it this way, what sign did you see driving down the highway?

Also this is a screenshot of a random selection of windows I have open - don't reinvent the wheel :)
[image]

**Update for Mac Users:**
I would say firstly go with what is right for the platform, but if it is a web app where that is not an option say I would also apply this example

- On a Windows *Quit* has the same connotations as a above
- On a Mac(/other) *Exit* is not the norm, however it is still expected and I beleive this would still be ok in terms of breaking the flow. It isn't like you are replacing Quit with [Renounce](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20renounce&oq=define%20reno&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4477j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) for example!

Comment: +1 Exit is the way to go... buildings have exit signs, roads have exits, many apps that have been around for a long time have Exit under the File menu as you've shown (though how odd is it that Ctrl+Q is for Exit in your SS, lol!)

Comment: Per Heng-Cheong Leong’s answer, the use of “Exit” on OS X would actually be considered wrong and surprising. Your three examples are from Windows; you’d find on a Mac that “Quit” is universal. In this case consistency is more important than obviousness. (Case in point: your example of iTunes—an Apple product—uses “Exit” on Windows.)

Comment: @bdesham Good point, though it doesn't answer the question what would be the right comprimise? I would still say Exit as on a mac it is clear and relatable but quit doesn't have same real life associations so on Windows would look even more odd if you weren't expecting it..

Comment: @tim.baker Why is a compromise needed? The OP is making a desktop app, so he should just use the OS convention. (In the case of a web app there’s no need for “Exit”/“Quit” anyway; you only “Log out”.)

Comment: @bdesham Not saying it is, as I mentioned in my edit it is more to future proof the question by saying if the scope changes or someone else is interested if it was for a webapp, for example, that would be the same respons :)

Comment: Web apps shouldn't have to "quit" or "exit." :-)

Comment: IIRC public signage in Britain uses "Way Out"

Comment: Gotta love the irony of `Ctrl+Q` and `Ctrl+Shift+Q` for "Exit" on your screen shoot. :-) On OSX it's `Cmd+Q` for Quit much about everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

### Since nobody has mentioned it:

Depending on your application you might have need for two terms. For example in chrome I can close the whole window, but I can also close just a tab. Same with Photoshop, my code editor, and a bunch of other UIs.
Having the same term for two different things is confusing (imagine if there was just one word for open and close).
For this reason there can be a valid use case for having two terms.

```
"**Close tab**" and "**Exit chrome**"
```

That could have been "Close tab" *and* "Close chrome", but better to **keep distinct actions distinctive**.

Aside from this above note to consider I recommend going with system defaults - it's a backbone principle of UI design as covered in [Neilsen's Heuristics: Consistency and standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_evaluation) as others answers note.
However: if possible have 'matching terms', e.g. **enter** matches **exit**, **open** matches **close**.

Personally I think **exit** is wrong for referring to an action you - *the user* - start.

1. [Exit dictionary definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exit) lists uses of the word for when the
   individual *exits*, whereas I am not actively leaving the
   application - I'm sitting right here - but only **the application**
   is leaving. So I would **Close** the application.
2. Also on my point about matching terms, I don't enter applications, I open them.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the 'Quit' action sounds more forceful, so it can be used to close an application which has failed to load or complete an action. It suggests the user wants the application to stop immediately. (For example, "Force Quit" on Mac OSX.) In contrast, the 'Exit' action sounds more gentle, so it can be used to stop an application after it has fully loaded.  'Exit' may prompt the user to save data, whereas 'Quit' will lose unsaved data.

However, as the accepted answer says, you should follow the UI guidelines for the relevant OS, to give the user a consistent experience.

Answer (score 2):

For an application, I would say that `"Quit"` is the most accurate and the user is most likely to understand this the best. It sounds more final, as if you are not planning on reopening the app in the current session.

`"Close"` feels more like you're hiding/removing a window, tab, or other widget/UI element. If you're talking about a mobile app, "close" gives the impression that you can reopen it again without relaunching the app, as if it is running in the background.

I can't think off the top of my head what use-case `"Exit"` is best suited for.

This is all from personal experience, but I would like to see it reinforced by a study.

Here's a posting from a mailing list, which I'm glad to see reiterates very closely what I've said above.
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/usability/2004-April/msg00092.html

Answer (score 1):

'Close' is the best answer since we open an application

We do not enter an application or start a process when we refer to working on an application, where we could have used exit or quit respectively

Comment: As other answers reveal - your logic is quite far from the norm.

Comment: Plus, we absolutely DO 'start' or 'launch' an application, rather than 'opening' it — although, quite often, that's done implicitly by 'opening' a file. But 'open' and 'close' tend to be applied to physical-object metaphors like windows and folders and files, not to more abstract concepts like an application or a user session. (Which is why you 'log in' to your account, you don't 'open' it.)

Comment: It also depends on the context and platform

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the impression you like a user to have when using your application.

If you want people to think someting like they are **in a game** or **on the Internet** then you should let them **exit** those places.

If people should simply **use** your application, you should let them **quit** using it.

Answer (score 1):

Although exit is frequently used I do think that Close is a better choice.

Most applications are created to make procedures easier and faster to perform. Lets say I have to write a paper. Instead of a notepad and a pen I will use MS Word.

Normally I would open my notepad and get a clean page but now I open a new document.
When Im done writing I close my notepad, now I close my document.

The word you use really depends on how you describe other functionality of your application.
if you have a MDI (Multiple Document Interface) application *Exit* would be the correct word since you already **open** many other windows in your application which are **closed**

With a SDI (Single Document Interface)application, such as Word I think Close would be a better choice, I can hear you say it, But you can open several documents at once. True.. However each document is opened in a seperate window.

Then the third option, *Quit*.. I think that really depends on what kind of application youre making. If its a game I think this will be a logical choice, other than that I dont see reason to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents on how I imagine the differences:

Exit - To press the x, alt+f4/ctrl q, or use the menu drop down to choose exit
Close - To use taskmanager/similar program to terminate the application
Quit - To leave the computer in frustration and never open the application again/uninstall it.