# I have a link that lets the user add, delete, modify elements. What should I call this link?

Tags: accessibility, guidelines, labels

I have this link that opens a modal popup where the user can add, modify and delete elements.
This link was formerly called "Add/Modify/Delete element".

This label is used repeatedly through my application, because there are several types of elements the user can Add, modify or delete (and an associated modal popup for each one of them)

I think this label is bad because it is too long and I guess the final user has to read it all before he/she can identify what type of element he/she can add,modify or delete.

So I came with possible other suggestions like "Edit element" and "Manage element", but I don't know if it is correct?

Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: "Maintain"  used to be very common for this, but it seems to have fallen out of fashion recently.

Comment: What do you mean **recently**!!? ;)

Answer (score 5):

You are absolutely right, that current label is very poor.

I would recommend

> Edit Element

Although edit by its self would be better, but it does depend on the context.

You will find this [list of guidelines set out by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511502.aspx#menuCategories) helpful to get your terminology correct.

Also see [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50893/do-we-exit-quit-or-close-an-application) as it is related to this but on the subject of Exit. Credit to @Heng-Cheong Leong for that link in the other question I mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You have the option of using a noun instead of a verb:

> Element Manager

or

> Elements Editor

I found these by thinking of something I already have a curation tool for (in this case my bookmarks) and then went looking to see what terminology was used there ("Bookmarks Manager" here in Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

I think **Manage Element** is suitable, because this word mean contain all operation which performed like add, update and delete.

Because In many software they use word like "Manage your application" and what we do in it ? Ans is simple. Add, update and delete.
So "Manage Element" is Good from my point of view.

"**Edit**", "**Update**" and "**Modify**" are with same meaning. You can only change existing data which are already present, No add and Delete in it. So its good to avoid that.

You can also use "Invoke Element Manager" if you can bit long label with something new.

So you have two selection

```
Manage Element
```

And

```
Invoke Element Manager
```

Comment: "Invoke Element Manager?" That invokes my obsolete phrase manager :P

Answer (score 2):

Instead of words, I think icons are probably a better way to go.  You can make them however big or small you want to fit whatever space requirements you have.  And they just look cleaner than words that are repeated for every element.

For add, delete, and modify you can use **plus**, **minus**, and **pencil** icons:

[image: add delete modify]

If you are going to be opening modals for each specific action, you could have all three icons by the elements.  However, if you simply want to open one modal where all actions can be performed, you just need the pencil icon.

Comment: Absolutely! Especially when you've got a long list of items, it's pretty tiresome to see "edit" "edit" "edit" ... all the way down.

Comment: @KenMohnkern - Exactly. It's just a cleaner approach that is more visually appealing, in my opinion.

Comment: You’d still need a suitable name (for example for screenreaders).

Comment: @unor - that's what the alt attribute is for.

Comment: @CodeMaverick: And what do you use as content for the (in case of `img`) `alt` attribute? [Hence](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50910/i-have-a-link-that-lets-the-user-add-delete-modify-elements-what-should-i-cal/50931?noredirect=1#comment76817_50931): "You’d still need a suitable name".

Comment: @unor - Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.  Are you simply saying the icons need their ids to match their action?  Or are you saying they need visible label names next to the icons?

Comment: @CodeMaverick: The OP asked for a textual label. You suggested to use icons instead. But the OP would still need a textual label, for example for the `alt` attribute. So the question still holds: How to label this link (but now: for screenreader users)?

Comment: @unor - Ok ... gotcha, it was what I originally thought you meant.  You simply use the `alt` attribute to describe each action for the icons: **add element**, **delete element**, **edit element**.  My original point still stands in the sense that you don't want textual links repeated throughout the page, as that would look horrible.  Icons would be suitable enough for the visually capable users.  For screen readers, the alt attribute can be as descriptive as you want it to be.  You aren't bound by visual design.

Answer (score 1):

I would either go for 'Manage Elements' or 'Actions'. Actions can include any kind of action that user can perform in that page. It is also understandable to a layman and makes it intuitive. I will not go with Edit as edit is not add or modify. IMHO, Users should be able to pick cues from looking at the control and guess what action it is going to perform.