# Do we "open" or "launch" or "start"apps?

Tags: terminology, text

A counterpart to [Do we “exit”, “quit” or "close" an application?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50893/do-we-exit-quit-or-close-an-application)...

Imagine you're browsing a list of apps and there's a button next to each one that will run the application when interacted with. Does it say "launch" or "open" or "start" （or something else)? What are the different contexts where each term should be used?

Comment: You might also be forgetting "run" an app

Comment: Yes. We do those things.

Answer (score 2):

**Semantic nuances**

- *Open* is generic and safe for almost all uses, but can feel dated, slow and static. [See related answer on related question.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/50896)
- *Launch* is a term full of movement: it feels dynamic, mobile and modern - but also is more specific to those environments. It is associated with clear, deliberate transitions - the opening of a new window; a 'launching' animation.
- *Start* refers specifically to the action of starting an app for the first time, and cannot be used to describe, for instance, re-opening a minimized/hidden/backgrounded app.

**Accessibility of language ([source](http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp?s=y))**

- *Open* is the 356th most common word in American English
- *Launch* is the 1756th most common word in American English
- *Start* is the 173rd most common word in American English
- Although *Open* is less common in general English usage, it is arguably a more prevalent concept in software than *Start* - simply because it is more versatile (see above).

Comment: I don't disagree with this, but it does feel very much opinion-based. I could see counter arguments to these that would be just as valid.

Answer (score 2):

A search on [Google trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=open%20application,start%20application,launch%20application,run%20application,execute%20application) for bigrams involving *application* and either *open*, *start*, *launch*, *run*, or *execute* reveals the following search trends:

[image: Google Trends search]

Apparently, *launch* and *execute* have been somewhat more frequent collocates of *application* at the beginning of the observation period, but are rarely searched for nowadays. These two may be out as options, then.

*Run* used to share the top ranking with *open*, but has fallen out of use somewhat over the last few years. *Start* shows a rather constant trend, and is now clearly in second place. Nevertheless, *open* appears to be most frequent search term together with *application*.

In conclusion, neither *run*, *start*, nor *open* are bad choices. Yet, based on [the principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), *open* might be the best candidate.